# Detect what specific page is open?

Tags: react-native

Pretty simple question.. does anyone have a solution for detecting what component is open in React Native? Treating a page like a component?

My solution right now is to use a global state manager like Redux or Mobx and just constantly update it with whatever component you have open.

Answer (score 0):

In you're renderScene property of your Navigator, you have access to the route object. So you can pass that down into whatever component you need.

```
    <Navigator
      configureScene={() => Navigator.SceneConfigs.FadeAndroid}
      style={styles.navigator}
      initialRoute={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
      renderScene={(route, navigator) => {
        if (route.title === Welcome) {
         return <Welcome navigator={navigator} route={route} />
         // Now inside Welcome, if you do this.props.route.title
         // you can access the current route name 'Welcome'
       }
      }}
    />
```